# Enable child form button

Tags: c#, winforms, parent-child

I Have parent form(FORM1) and I added this code

```
FORM2 form = new FORM2();
form.Show();
```

what I want is to enable one specific button (which is disabled by default) when my child form is called(opened) from parent. Can you please give me example how to do it

Comment: so add `button.Enabled = true` right after you call show.  What else is there to do?

Comment: Is the button on the parent or child form?

Comment: button is on child form. What I'm trying to do is: when I click on button on parent form it execute code above and child form appears. But also it enables one specific button on that child form that was disabled by default

Comment: Why is the button disabled on the child form by default?  If you just enable it every time you open the form just change the default setting of the button to enabled.

Comment: It is disabled because I dont want users to use it before. I have 2 different forms calling this one. And when one form is calling button stays disabled, when other form is calling button should be enabled

Comment: That's all fairly key information that you should edit into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to add a property like this one to your child form:

```
public bool MyButtonEnabled //TODO give better name
{
    get
    {
        //TODO change this to the button that you're using
        return button1.Enabled;
    }
    set
    {
        //TODO change this to the button that you're using
        button1.Enabled = value;
    }
}
```

You can then use that property from the parent form(s) to change the visibility of the button.

Using a property such as this is much better, from a design perspective, than exposing the button publicly as you limit the ability of external entities to do only what they need to without giving them way more access then they need.